# Erro Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Estou atualizando um .rpt, que funcionava perfeitamente, porém precisei fazer algumas alterações, e ele me retorna erro:
Segue o código de como é carregado o relatório Crystal Report:

```
  SqlConnection connection = clsdb.AbreBanco();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select dbo.CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE, produto_pedido.data, dbo.CLIENTE.NOME_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.CNPJ_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.CPF_CLIENTE,dbo.CLIENTE.TIPO_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.TEL_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.CEL_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.EMAIL_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.OBS_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.SITUACAO_CLIENTE, dbo.CLIENTE.DATAATE, dbo.CLIENTE.RESPONSAVEL_CLIENTE,  dbo.CLIENTE.CRACHASHAVER,dbo.CLIENTE.INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL, dbo.CLIENTE.REPRESENTANTE_COMERCIAL, dbo.CLIENTE.SITE, dbo.CLIENTE.FAX, dbo.CLIENTE.OBS_CONTATO, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.ID,  dbo.PRODUTO.DESCRICAO_PRODUTO, dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO.QTD, dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO.VALOR, dbo.PRODUTO.FORNECEDOR_PRODUTO, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.FRETE, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.FORMA_COBRANCA, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.FORMA_PAGAMENTO, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.PREVISAO_ENTREGA, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.FORMA_INST_APAR, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.RESPONSAVEL, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.TELEFONE, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.DATA_PREVISTA, dbo.PRODUTO.TIPO, dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.VALOR_TOTAL, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.RUA_FATURA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.N_FATURA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.BAIRRO_FATURA,PRODUTO_PEDIDO.UF_FATURA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CIDADE_FATURA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CEP_FATURA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.RUA_ENTREGA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.N_ENTREGA,PRODUTO_PEDIDO.BAIRRO_ENTREGA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.UF_ENTREGA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CIDADE_ENTREGA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CEP_ENTREGA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.RUA_COBRANCA,PRODUTO_PEDIDO.N_COBRANCA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.BAIRRO_COBRANCA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.UF_COBRANCA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CIDADE_COBRANCA, PRODUTO_PEDIDO.CEP_COBRANCA FROM dbo.CLIENTE inner join dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO on PRODUTO_PEDIDO.ID_CLIENTE = CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE inner join dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO on dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO = dbo.PRODUTO_PEDIDO.ID inner join dbo.PRODUTO on dbo.PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO where dbo.PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO =  " + id, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "CLIENTE");
        ReportDocument Myreport = new ReportDocument();
        Myreport.Load(@"\\SERVER\atende\Atendimento Domínio\Relatorio_PEDIDOCOMPRA.rpt");
        Myreport.SetDataSource(dataset.Tables["CLIENTE"]);
        Myreport.SetParameterValue("imagem", @"\\Server\atende\Relatórios\logo.png");
        Myreport.SetParameterValue("documento", documento);
        Myreport.SetParameterValue("nomedocumento", nomedocumento);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Myreport;
```

Porém ele trava, ele chega a abrir o report, mas não aparece os dados, ele me dá erro nesta linha:

```
Myreport.SetDataSource(dataset.Tables["CLIENTE"]);
```

Não foi mudado esta parte, foi mudado só uma escrita no report, não sei o porque está acontecendo isso. Ele não retorna o erro, consegui descobrir que era esta linha depurando o código, e logo em seguida a execução para.  Alguém pode me ajudar?

EDIT:
Acabei mexendo um pouco mais, e descobri o erro que ele me retorna:

> O inicializador de tipo de 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ReportSourceFactory' acionou uma exceção.

Já tentei várias coisas, desinstalar e instalar de novo, verificar dlls, referenciar de novo, porém todas sem sucesso.

Comment: a estrutura da tabela "CLIENTE" está igual a estrutura utilizada no report ?

Comment: Sim, não foi mudado nada no código c# e nem na estrutura do banco, apenas no arquivo rpt.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis editei a pergunta.

Comment: `ReportSourceFactory` adicionou uma exceção. Qual exceção foi essa ? deve ter mais dados aí

Comment: @RovannLinhalis agora ele não está mais dando o erro, apenas aparece tudo cinza e não carrega o relatório, no form do projeto ele aparece.

Comment: @marianac_costa, o que você mudou para não estar mais dando erro?

Comment: Nossa na minha máquina consegui fazer funcionar, porém na do cliente ainda não, eu tive que desinstalar o crystal report, instalar o 64 bits q é a minha máquina, instalar o crystal pra visual studio, para assim funcionar. A do cliente, irei fazer o teste, ele retorna erro falando que não encontro o reportdocument, provavelmente é algo com a instalação do crystal report.